# reading in a file c small error big problems

Tags: c, file, matrix, fopen

I am trying to fill 2 matrices from 2 data text files but the compiler is telling me I have conflicting types for the "infiles" (1&2) but if I take out FILE I get a casting error and if I take out infile =fopen i get no output at all for matrices but it does compile. nothing seems to work right

the problem code:

```
FILE *infile1;
FILE *infile2;

*infile1 = (int)fopen("m1.dat","r");
*infile2 = (int)fopen("m2.dat","r");
```

full code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>


#define M 4
#define K 4
#define N 4

void *runner(void *param); /* the thread */

int A [M][K];
int B [K][N];
int C [M][N];

struct v {
   int i; // row
   int j; // column
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //using namespace std;
//ifstream infile1 ("m1.dat");
//ifstream infile2 ("m2.dat");

int infile1 = (int)fopen("m1.dat","r");
int infile2 = (int)fopen("m2.dat","r");

FILE *infile1;
FILE *infile2;

//if (!infile1)  //testing files
    // cerr << "Error: could not open input file 1\n";
//if (!infile2)  //testing files
     //cerr << "Error: could not open input file 2\n";

if (!infile1)  //testing files
    fprintf(stderr, "file 1 missing\n");
        exit(1);

if (!infile2)  //testing files
    fprintf(stderr, "file 2 missing\n");
        exit(1);

int i, j, size1, size2 =0;
//infile1 >> size1;
//infile2 >> size2;
fscanf(infile1,"%d",&size1);
fscanf(infile2,"%d",&size2);
float s = (float)size1;
int dim = (int)sqrt(s);


for(i=0;i<M;i++){
 for(j=0;j<N;j++){
  //infile1 >> A[i][j];
 // infile2 >> B[i][j];
  fscanf(infile1,"%d",&A[i][j]);
  fscanf(infile2,"%d",&B[i][j]);
 }
}
 for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
    if ((j  % dim)==0) printf("\n");
        printf("%d \t",A[i][j]);
 }
}

printf("\n\n");

  for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
    if ((j  % dim)==0) printf("\n");;
        printf("%d \t",B[i][j]);
 }
}

printf("\n\n");

int count = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < M; i++) { //column
      for(j = 0; j < N; j++) { //row
         //Assign a row and column for each thread
         struct v *data = (struct v *) malloc(sizeof(struct v));
         data->i = i;
         data->j = j;
         // Now create the thread passing it data as a parameter
         pthread_t tid;       //Thread ID
         pthread_attr_t attr; //Set of thread attributes
         //Get the default attributes
         pthread_attr_init(&attr);
         //Create the thread
         pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,data);
         //Make sure the parent waits for all thread to complete
         pthread_join(tid, NULL);
         count++;
      }
   }

   //Print out the resulting matrix
   for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
         printf("%d ", C[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

   printf("\n \n");

  fclose(infile1);
  fclose(infile2);
return 0;
}

//The thread will begin control in this function
void *runner(void *param) {
   struct v *data = (struct v*)param; // the structure that holds our data
   int n, sum = 0; //the counter and sum

   //Row multiplied by column
   for(n = 0; n< K; n++){
      sum += A[data->i][n] * B[n][data->j];
   }
   //assign the sum to its coordinate
   C[data->i][data->j] = sum;

   pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Edit: Latest version of code. Still just outputs nothing to the screen. Even have a printf that should run right before it closes and that doesnt even work. The only thing I did change from a working versiion(it used to do it correctly) was that the things related to the opening of the file were in C++ and I changed it to C. No idea why I don't get any errors though. Here is my latest full code. the output looks like this  http://tinypic.com/r/21185u9/9

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>


#define M 4
#define K 4
#define N 4

void *runner(void *param); /* the thread */

int A [M][K];
int B [K][N];
int C [M][N];

struct v {
   int i; // row
   int j; // column
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

FILE *infile1 = fopen("m1.dat","r");
FILE *infile2 = fopen("m2.dat","r");

if (infile1 == NULL)  //testing files
//if (!infile1)  //testing files
    //fprintf(stderr, "file 1 missing\n");
    perror("File 1 Missing");
        exit(1);

if (infile2 == NULL)  //testing files
//if (!infile1)  //testing files
    //fprintf(stderr, "file 1 missing\n");
    perror("File 2 Missing");
        exit(1);

int i, j, size1, size2 =0;

fscanf(infile1,"%d",&size1);
fscanf(infile2,"%d",&size2);
float s = (float)size1;
int dim = (int)sqrt(s);


for(i=0;i<M;i++){
 for(j=0;j<N;j++){
  fscanf(infile1,"%d",&A[i][j]);
  fscanf(infile2,"%d",&B[i][j]);
 }
}
 for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
    if ((j  % dim)==0) printf("\n");
        printf("%d \t",A[i][j]);
 }
}

printf("\n\n");

  for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
    if ((j  % dim)==0) printf("\n");;
        printf("%d \t",B[i][j]);
 }
}

printf("\n\n");

int count = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < M; i++) { //column
      for(j = 0; j < N; j++) { //row
         //Assign a row and column for each thread
         struct v *data = (struct v *) malloc(sizeof(struct v));
         data->i = i;
         data->j = j;
         // Now create the thread passing it data as a parameter
         pthread_t tid;       //Thread ID
         pthread_attr_t attr; //Set of thread attributes
         //Get the default attributes
         pthread_attr_init(&attr);
         //Create the thread
         pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,data);
         //Make sure the parent waits for all thread to complete
         pthread_join(tid, NULL);
         count++;
      }
   }

   //Print out the resulting matrix
   for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
         printf("%d ", C[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

   printf("\n \n");
   printf("program ran");

    fclose(infile1);
    fclose(infile2);
return 0;

}


//The thread will begin control in this function
void *runner(void *param) {
   struct v *data = (struct v*)param; // the structure that holds our data
   int n, sum = 0; //the counter and sum

   //Row multiplied by column
   for(n = 0; n< K; n++){
      sum += A[data->i][n] * B[n][data->j];
   }
   //assign the sum to its coordinate
   C[data->i][data->j] = sum;
   pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: [`fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) and `fread`/`fwrite` etc. use a `FILE *`, not `int`. If you make it so, that compiler error should go away.

Comment: The error message 'you have conflicting types for `infile1`', means that you use `infile` as being one type in one place, and another type in another place. A variable can only have one type.

Comment: `infile1 = fopen ("m1.dat","r");` and the same for `infile2` are all you need. Make sure you check that the open succeeded afterward. e.g. `if (!infile1) { fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed 'm1.dat'.\n"); return 1; }` and the same for `infile2`. You also need to enclose file checks in `{...}` to prevent `exit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from declaring the return value from the file open function incorrectly.

Instead of using your problem code, use:

```
FILE *infile1 = fopen("m1.dat","r");
FILE *infile2 = fopen("m2.dat","r");
```

It declares infile1 and infile2 as pointers to the FILE type with the values properly set depending on how successful the file can be opened. In simple terms, call infile1 and infile2 as file handles.

If you want an integer value as the return value, you can look into the `open()` function instead of `fopen()`, but `fopen()` works well in your case.

Comment: when I try it that way nothing appears

Comment: You have to make sure the files you are reading into the program are in the format the program can understand.

Comment: I'm referring to the actual contents of the file, not the extension. For example, if the file actually contains garbage, then your program will have a hard time properly processing it. You might want to run your program using a debugger or add extra printf statements in your program to see data values while the program is running.

Comment: hmmm I had translated the reading in of a file from c++ to c. when I left it as c++ it read the contents correctly so I don't think it's junk. but when I say ./a.out (compiling in linux) it just goes to next line like  http://tinypic.com/r/21185u9/9

Comment: do you have copies of the same data file that you're trying to read? maybe you're using the wrong copy? You should be debugging your program. I like using printf after each variable for debugging so I know the value of each variable as it is set.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the exit status of your *edited code*, you will find that it is `1` due to exiting after the first file check. In your code you have:

```
if (infile1 == NULL)  //testing files
//if (!infile1)  //testing files
    //fprintf(stderr, "file 1 missing\n");
    perror("File 1 Missing");
        exit(1);
```

Which will run the `exit(1)` function every time (even if `infile1` is OK). You need to properly contain `exit` within the scope of your check with `{...}`. e.g.:

```
if (infile1 == NULL) {  //testing files
    perror ("File 1 Missing");
    exit (1);
}
```

and the same for `infile2`. I have not checked the remainder of your code.

Comment: Thanks that did it! I was so focused in changing the file read in from c++ to c I didn't even check that. If I was the one to write the file in code I would have made sure to check for {} at the beginning of my my if